# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Dual Screen Logs out

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I have 2 displays connected to my Nvidia Titan Graphics. One is on the DVI port and other thru display port.

When I open a application on the second display connected thru display port, the system logs out immediately. However, openning an application on screen connected via DVI and dragging it to other one does not cause this problem.

What can be an issue here?

Comment: try searching the /var/log/xorg.0.log for more information, not a bad idea to review the other logs too

Comment: I realized that my second monitor is rotated anticlockwise which causes this issue. Changing the rotation to normal, the error goes away. Perhaps its due to different screen resolution which might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that one off the screen was vga so when I rotated it side ways the above problem happens. But when not rotated there is no problem.